# How to see the difference in two strings

Tags: r

I'm trying to find the difference between two columns in a CSV file, which I named Test.

[image: File example]

I'd like to add a new column called 'Results' that contains the difference between Events_1 & Events_2. If there is no difference the Results can be blank.
This is a basic example, for what I'm trying to accomplish, the real list contains hundreds of events in both columns.

Comment: No one except you can use that without tediously retyping it.  Please note the instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag page not to use images.

Comment: Untested: `Map(setdiff, strsplit(x$Events_2, "[,\\s]+"), strsplit(x$Events_1, "[,\\s]+"))`.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested with your data, but

```r
vec2 <- c("hello,goodbye","hello,goodbye")
vec1 <- c("hello","hello,goodbye")
Map(setdiff, strsplit(vec2, "[,\\s]+"), strsplit(vec1, "[,\\s]+"))
# [[1]]
# [1] "goodbye"
# [[2]]
# character(0)
```

If you need them to be comma-delimited strings, then

```r
mapply(function(a,b) paste(setdiff(a,b), collapse=","), strsplit(vec2, "[,\\s]+"), strsplit(vec1, "[,\\s]+"))
# [1] "goodbye" ""
```